# Migration of Java Applets to Java WebStart and GWT

Tags: java, security, gwt, applet, java-web-start

I have an application that uses a "**signed**" applet which is packaged inside a jar that does the following things:

1. Checks whether the file exists in the directory while uploading a file and opens a form for details.
   An applet is included in JSP and checks the file exists in local system by getting storage path while uploading.
2. Checks whether the applet is active and downloads the file to local system.
3. Add files to application that will be stored as local copy in file system.

As the support for applets is getting removed, I would want to migrate from applets. I would like to know is Java Web Start the best option for replacing applets in terms of "**security, trusted code**" and signature. Are there any other technologies that comes useful for my application in the above areas?

Also found that 
[Migrate Java Applet to what/where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728379/migrate-java-applet-to-what-where)

[Replace Applet in downloading and executing a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899577/replace-applet-in-downloading-and-executing-a-file)

Any suggestions on this?